# Having issue getting volume information to populate in csv file with multiple columns for each drive

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to run a script from my computer on multiple servers to gather daily metric reports. I need it to be open due to demand in servers being added so the group is filtered by ou. I am struggling to get all the volume information pulled from each server into the below generated CSV file.

I would appreciate any help you can offer! I will also need to import all the data output onto each server and combine it into one excel spreadsheet. Still learning to write and navigate scripting, please, don't be harsh lol

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

# Select the servers you want to hit
$servers = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=OUGROUP" -filter *).name

$scriptblock = {
# Set the server name
$serverName = $env:computername
 
# Get the up/down status of the server
$pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1
$status = if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 0) { "Up" } else { "Down" }
 
# Get the server build date
$os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$buildDate = $os.InstallDate
 
# Get the server certificate validity
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | Sort-Object -Property NotBefore | Select-Object -First 1
$validFrom = $cert.NotBefore
$validTo = $cert.NotAfter
 
# Check for full drives (this is still having issues) I cant seem to get the information to populate in the CSV file.
$DriveSize = get_volume

#Check Trellix update
$TrellixDate = [datetime](get-itemproperty "C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater\amupdate.dat").lastwritetime.DateTime 
 
# Create a custom object with the collected information
$serverInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ServerName = $serverName
    Status = $status
    BuildDate = $buildDate.datetime
    CertificateValidFrom = $validFrom
    CertificateValidTo = $validTo
    FullDrives = $DriveSize | -list
    TrellixLastUpdate = $TrellixDate
}
 
# Export the information to a CSV file
$serverInfo | Export-Csv -Path "\temp\ServerInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
Write-Host "Server information exported to ServerInfo.csv"
 
#command to run the script on the servers 
foreach ($server in $servers){
invoke-command -computername $server -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
}
```

I can get all of the output except the volume information to populate how I want. Above is the current working script that I have (some identifying information redacted)

Comment: Typo: `get_volume` -> `Get-Volume`. It's unclear what `| -list` is meant to, but you can just remove it. Pinging each server _from itself_, as part of the remotely executing code doesn't make much sense. Is the intent really to export the CSV to a file _on each server_? Note that it's not only simpler but also faster to pass _all_ server names to a _single_ `Invoke-Command` call: you'll get _parallel_ processing: `invoke-command -computername $servers -ScriptBlock $scriptblock`, without the enclosing `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your script from the AD with task scheduler.

Here is the missing part for the disks:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

foreach($server in Get-ADComputer -Filter "*") {
  Write-Host $server.Name

  foreach ($disk in (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server.Name -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3"))    {
    $diskLabel = $disk.DeviceID
    $freeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
    $diskSize = $disk.Size / 1GB
    $percent = $freeSpace / $diskSize * 100
    
    #just use these variables for your csv.
    Write-Host $diskLabel " Free: " $freeSpace "GB | Full size: " $diskSize "GB | Percent: " $percent "%" 
    #TODO your code...
  }
}
```

Feel free to ask. If it was helpful just accept the answer.

---

EDIT: You can run the `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk` script on your own computer.

This will be the output:
[image]

Full script output on your own computer without the first foreach:
[image]

Comment: Do i put this in the $serverInfo pscustom object space or do I add this outside? Assuming that I should be replacing that post where $fulldrives is. Or am I wrong? Apologies, once again for not being fully understanding with this

Comment: If you are just learning powershell, I suggest you download a vs code and in debug mode see when and which variable takes which value. You will understand it more easily.
Try running this script by itself.
Inside the "Win32_LogicalDisk class" you will get the "DeviceID", which is the partition ID (C,D,E etc.), in addition to the "FreeSpace" and the "Size", which is the total disk size. After that you can easily calculate the space consumption (FreeSpace / Size * 100)

Comment: I left the write-host part in just to see the output. Make your custom object from those variables, or just add the variables to the one you have now.

Comment: You are the best KKI! I had to manipulate it a little. I used the foreach and modified it, moved the label, freespace. disksize and percent to the pscustomobject part. I was able to get at least ONE drive to show up in the csv.

Comment: Than accept the answer and press the upvote button please ;) Great job.